# How can I handle Big Int with GraphQL?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I've an Django Model field with BigInt type, How can i map this in graphql schema, is there anything available like `BigInt` like `Int` type in Graphql?

I'm using [graphene](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene) library FYI

My Schema:

```
type MyModelObject {
  complaintId: BigInt
  createdBy: User!
  complaintNumber: String!
}
```

I got below warning/error in IDE

```bash
The field type 'BigInt' is not present when resolving type 'MyModelObject'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for this, AFAIK. But the GraphQL custom scalars are designed for this kind of requirement. You can use Graphene Custom scalars to define a new scalar type for BigInt.

```python
from graphene.types import Scalar
from graphql.language import ast

class BigInt(Scalar):
    '''BigInt Scalar Description'''

    @staticmethod
    def serialize(bigInt):
        # Can serialize this by converting it to a string.
        return str(bigInt)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_literal(node, _variables=None):
        # Parse literal

    @staticmethod
    def parse_value(value):
        # Parse the value
```

Check the [Graphene documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/scalars/#custom-scalars) for more information.